# Get the node ID from the "node/add" menu item and hook_form_alter()

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, hooks

I want to set a unique 7-digit code to a custom content type and display it in a disabled textfield when a node is created. I created a CCK textfield and set it to disabled in hook_form_alter, great.

I think that a good way to make this unique ID is just to use the node id and fill it out to the required length (eg. 0000012). It doesn't look like $nid is available at the node/add form though. How can I set this ID field to default to the `$nid`? Can I access the `hook_form_alter()` as the content is created (on form submission)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a field in PHP.

It can keep its own serial counter in a variable, and auto-fill itself with that. You can create formatters for all the different use cases yourself.

Field example code here: http://drupal.org/project/examples

Also I made a UUID field you could hack on: http://drupal.org/sandbox/Mile23/1326218

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the nid is not available at this point, it's assigned only after the the node is saved.

The easiest solution is most probably to use [`hook_node_insert`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) and resave the node after having added the value to the field you have created.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/7), which the function used to save a node, the hooks that are invoked after drupal_write_record(), which is the function used to set the node ID, are the following ones (when the node is created):

- [hook_node_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7)
- [hook_entity_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7)

```
// Call the node specific callback (if any). This can be
// node_invoke($node, 'insert') or
// node_invoke($node, 'update').
node_invoke($node, $op);

// Save fields.
$function = "field_attach_$op";
$function('node', $node);

module_invoke_all('node_' . $op, $node);
module_invoke_all('entity_' . $op, $node, 'node');
```

> Can I access the `hook_form_alter()` as the content is created (on form submission)?

`hook_form_alter()` is invoked for a node edit form whenever the node is being created, or the node is being updated. You can add a custom submission handler from `hook_form_alter()`, which then is able to alter the node being saved.
The hooks I have reported should be sufficient for what you want to do, though.